# Showing an inequality with complex modulus.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ where $|z|<1$. Prove the inequality
$$\left|-1+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right|<|z|.$$

I am having trouble showing this. All my attempts have failed. Here is one attempt that I believe is most promising, but I am stuck.
$$ |z|=\left|i\sqrt{z^2}\right|=\left|1-1+\sqrt{-1+1-z^2}\right|$$
This must be greater than $\left|-1+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right|$ but I can't figure out how. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Substitute $\sqrt{\frac{1-z}{1+z}}=w$. This is a particular case of [this well known magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#The_third_substitution_of_Euler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\;\;\displaystyle\left|-1+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right| \cdot \left|-1-\sqrt{1-z^2}\right| = |z|^2\,$, therefore:

$$\left|-1+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right| \le |z| \;\;\iff\;\; \left|-1+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right| \le \left|-1-\sqrt{1-z^2}\right|$$

But the principal value of the square root $\,w = \sqrt{1-z^2}\,$ always lies in the right half-plane $\,\operatorname{Re}(w) \ge 0\,$, so it is geometrically obvious that the distance $\,w-1\,$ from $w$ to $+1$ is no larger than the distance $w+1$ from $w$ to $-1$.